# Firebase Storage, onSuccessListener not doing as intended

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, event-listener

I've been trying to create an app which uses Firebase authentication, Firebase storage and Firebase database. Im trying to get the downloadURI from the successListener but it never reaches, and the toast never displays. However, in Firebase Storage it has successfully created a folder with profilepictures and uploaded the image. I dont see what im doing wrong, so any help is appreciated!

```
public class RegisterLastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText displayName;
private Button cheersButton;
private ImageView profilePicture;

private Uri imageFile;
private boolean imageFileChosen = false;

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_last);

    displayName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displayname);
    cheersButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheers_button);
    profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    cheersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendToStorage(imageFile);
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterLastActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
}

public void imagePressed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        setImageFile(uri);
        imageFileChosen = true;
        Log.d("OnActivityResult", "imageFileChosen " + String.valueOf(imageFileChosen));
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            //Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected void sendToStorage(Uri uri){
    if(imageFileChosen){
        StorageReference storageReference = mStorageRef.child("Profilepictures").child(getCurrentToken());
        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterLastActivity.this, "Kom inn til success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose an image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected String getCurrentToken(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        return user.getUid();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setImageFile(Uri imageFile) {
    this.imageFile = imageFile;
}
}
```

This doesnt produce any error messages in Android Monitor. Look for sendToStorage(Uri uri) method, that's where i have the error. I had to include the @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") because it gives me an annoying error without.

Comment: Just a thought: Have you tried swapping `putFile` and `addListener`?

Comment: Ignore the above, you can't swap those

Comment: Yeh, cant swap those :S